# Python Regex-- TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, regex, typeerror

I am receiving an error on the .match regex module function of TypeError: An integer is required.

Here is my code:

```
hAndL = hAndL.replace('epsilo\ell','epsilon')
pattern = re.compile("\frac{.*?}{ \frac{.*?}{.*?}}")
matching = pattern.match(pattern,hAndL)
```

hAndL is a string and pattern is a..pattern.

I'm not sure why this error is happening, any help is appreciated!

Comment: The 2nd argument to `match()` is a starting position integer, not a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) a regular expression, you *don't need to pass the regex object back to itself*. Per the documentation:

> The sequence
>
> ```
> prog = re.compile(pattern)
> result = prog.match(string)
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> result = re.match(pattern, string)
> ```

The `pattern` is already provided, so in your example:

```
pattern.match(pattern, hAndL)
```

is equivalent to:

```
re.match(pattern, pattern, hAndL)
                # ^ passing pattern twice
                         # ^ hAndL becomes third parameter
```

where the third parameter to [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) is `flags`, which must be an integer. Instead, you should do:

```
pattern.match(hAndL)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
hAndL = hAndL.replace('epsilo\ell','epsilon')
pattern = re.compile("\frac{.*?}{ \frac{.*?}{.*?}}")
matching = pattern.match(hAndL)
```